# Adding LostGrid to Ruby on Rails with webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, postcss

First poster here.
I just created a new Rails project with webpack (`rails new myapp --webpack`). It comes with PostCSS and I wanted to add [LostGrid](https://github.com/peterramsing/lost) to it. I ran the following, from the installation [instructions](https://github.com/peterramsing/lost/wiki/Installation#webpack) from Lost:

```
npm install --save lost
```

This added Lost to `package.json`. The instructions then say to add the following to your webpack config, assuming you have postcss-loader installed & configured (which I understand was installed automatically when the project was created):

```
postcss: [
  require('lost')
]
```

But I don't understand where the file is. I thought that I needed to add my PostCSS stuff to `.postcssrc.yml` in the root. I did this but I still don't get it to work.

I have very little experience with webpack and suspect that my approach is entirely flawed. I was excited to use PostCSS in Rails and would appreciate any help in getting to make LostGrid work here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found your question moments after I ran into the same issue. Fortunately it's really simple!

When you run `webpacker:install` it installs a file called `.postcssrc.yml` in the root folder of the project. This is where you add the`PostCSS` plugins. Mine now looks like this:

```
  plugins:
      lost: {}
      postcss-smart-import: {}
      postcss-cssnext: {}
      autoprefixer: {}
```

I am not sure yet whether the order matters. Still researching that.

See [Webpacker issue #283](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/283) which is essentially the same question, but without an example provided.

Comment: Yes, order matters :)